# Careers: Why is the export called 'résumé' when everywhere else it's CV?

Tags: discussion, jobs, export

Just askin'

(Oh, and I know that's the stateside terminology, just wondering why the export is different)

bug tag because I had to pick one.

Comment: `just wondering why the export is different` -- Erm, because Stack Exchange is an American company? Just sayin'.

Comment: I don't understand how that explains the difference. Why is it a CV in the first place, instead of Résumé everywhere?

Comment: Cultural hegemony. You know what it means anyway...

Comment: Because when you export, you're downgrading your representation medium

Comment: I just recall Jeff's explanation of why they used 'CV' instead of résumé on one of the Podcasts. I thought it might be an inconsistency thing so I just thought I'd ask

Comment: CV is used quite often inside of the US as well. But it has a decidedly more academic or elitist feel to it.

Comment: Perhaps the better question is, "Why do you hate freedom?"

Answer (score 1):

The Résumé export was conceived as a summary of your profile (formerly referred to as your CV) in which you only include information specific to the position you are applying to and to be used as something you could attach to an email, instead of asking them to visit our website to see your info.

Exported Résumés were designed to be an artifact you could pass around until we convince everyone that the canonical place to find out all about your techie prowess is by visiting your Careers 2.0 profile (no timeline on that yet however).

If the name is all that matters, you could write a script to change Résumé to CV everywhere on that page and then post it on https://stackapps.com/?tab=scripts and use it when applying to jobs to **show** how good you are at making awesome things.